# Given an array of integers. Find the LARGEST subarray with the MAXIMUM sum

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

Hi I am preparing for an interview code test and I stumbled across this question. I tried attempting it in C#, below is my embarrasing answer which I don't even know if it's right but mostly I guess not, could someone please kindly provide me with the answer so that when I rework on the solution I can at least have the answer to verify the output. Thanks.

Sample data:

```
int[] arr = {5, 1, -7, 3, 7};
```

Code:

```
int[] LargestsubarrayMaxSum(int[] arr)
{
    int temp = 0;
    int[] resultArr = new int[arr.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        if (i != 0)
        {
            foreach (int item in resultArr)
            {
                temp += item;
            }

            if (temp + arr[i + 1] > 0)
            {
                resultArr[i + 1] = temp + arr[i + 1];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if ((arr[i] + arr[i + 1]) >= 0)
            {
                resultArr[i] = arr[i];
                resultArr[i + 1] = arr[i] + arr[i + 1];
            }
            else
            {
                resultArr[i] = arr[i];
                resultArr[i + 1] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return resultArr;
}
```

Comment: Is this basically saying to return all positive integers?  How big can the largest sub-array be?

Comment: @Adam - I would assume that the largest sub-array is the entire array if all values are positive.

Comment: @Lieven exactly what I was thinking :-)

Comment: @Adam for this problem, 'subarray' is not the same thing as 'subset' - a subarray is made up of *contiguous* elements from the source array

Comment: @AakashM ah, that is the crux of the problem, I knew I wasn't seeing it.  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: I still don't understand. "Largest subarray with maximum sum." Why is 4+5+-2+1 = 8 better than 4+5 = 9. Now, obviously, the former has more elements.. but how do you decide which is better..

Answer (score 9):

How about this?

```
var arr = new [] {5, 1, -7, 3, 7};

var xs =
    from n in Enumerable.Range(0, arr.Length)
    from l in Enumerable.Range(1, arr.Length - n)
    let subseq = arr.Skip(n).Take(l)
    orderby subseq.Count() descending
    orderby subseq.Sum() descending
    select subseq;

var maxSumSubseq = xs.First();
```

EDIT: Added `orderby subseq.Count() descending` to get maximal length subsequence.

---

EDIT: Added explanation as per comment.

1. Select all possible subsequence starting indices:

   ```
   from n in Enumerable.Range(0, arr.Length)
   ```
2. Select all possible lengths of subsequences given the starting index:

   ```
   from l in Enumerable.Range(1, arr.Length - n)
   ```
3. Extract the subsequence from the array:

   ```
   let subseq = arr.Skip(n).Take(l)
   ```
4. Order subsequences by descending length (i.e. longest first) - could order by `l` instead of `subseq.Count()` but the latter is more expressive even though the former is more efficient:

   ```
   orderby subseq.Count() descending
   ```
5. Calculate the sum of each subsequence and order the subsequences so highest valued sums are first:

   ```
   orderby subseq.Sum() descending
   ```
6. Select the subsequences:

   ```
   select subseq;
   ```
7. Only select the first subsequence - it's the highest value sum with the greatest length:

   ```
   xs.First();
   ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: can't guarantee that this result will give you the right answer for `var arr = new [] {5,1,-7,2,2,2}`

Comment: +1 For all the variations I've tried, it returned the correct result but you might want to explain one another. I have no idea how this works.

Comment: @Lieven - I added an explanation of each line. Let me know if this helps or not. Cheers.

Answer (score 7):

**O(N) time complexity and O(1) space complexity**. This is the optimal solution I know:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int get_max_sum(int* array, int len, int* start, int* end)
{
    int max_sum = INT_MIN, sum = 0, i;
    int tmp_start = 0;

    for(i = 0; i != len; ++i)
    {
        sum += array[i];

        // if the sum is equal, choose the one with more elements
        if(sum > max_sum || (sum == max_sum && (end - start) < (i - tmp_start)))
        {
            max_sum = sum;
            *start = tmp_start;
            *end = i;
        }
        if(sum < 0)
        {
            sum = 0;
            tmp_start = i + 1;
        }
    }

    return max_sum;
}
```

Here are some test cases:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int arr1[] = {5, 1, -7, 3, 7};
    int arr2[] = {1};
    int arr3[] = {-1, -7, -3, -7};
    int arr4[] = {5, 1, -7, 2, 2, 2};
    int start, end, sum;

    sum = get_max_sum(arr1, 5, &start, &end);
    printf("sum: %d, start: %d, end: %d\n", sum, start, end);

    sum = get_max_sum(arr2, 1, &start, &end);
    printf("sum: %d, start: %d, end: %d\n", sum, start, end);

    sum = get_max_sum(arr3, 4, &start, &end);
    printf("sum: %d, start: %d, end: %d\n", sum, start, end);

    sum = get_max_sum(arr4, 6, &start, &end);
    printf("sum: %d, start: %d, end: %d\n", sum, start, end);

    return 0;
}

$ ./a.out
sum: 10, start: 3, end: 4
sum: 1, start: 0, end: 0
sum: -1, start: 0, end: 0
sum: 6, start: 3, end: 5
```

**Update1**:
Added code to print the index of the subarray.

**Update2**:
If two sub arrays with the same sum are found, choose the one with more elements.

**Update3**:
Fix the algorithm for leading negative numbers

Comment: But you are not giving the largest subarray, it is giving only the SUM.

Comment: Code for getting the subarray is added. I thought it was not difficult so I didn't add it in the first place.

Comment: @Mu Qiao - as OP needs the *largest* subarray, testcase #4 should return `sum: 6, start: 3, end: 5`.

Comment: @Lieven "start: 0, end: 1" is also the largest one. I know there are two largest subarrays but I just return the first one. Finding all of them requires more code which makes it difficult to understand.

Comment: @Mu Qiao - What you are describing is the max sum. Array 0-1 consists of 2 elements, array 3-5 consists of 3 elements. I believe *that* is what is meant by largest subarray.

Comment: @Lieven Now I get it and fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: I love when someone writes exactly what I need. Thanks.

Comment: This algorithm fails with an entry like: -1, 2, 3. In general, looks like it fails if the first element is negative.

Comment: I have to note though it finds subarray with maximum **positive** sum.

Answer (score 4):

You could either use Enigmativity's answer but add the extra order by of `subseq.Count() descending`

or if you want an insane linq query......

```
int[] arr = .......

var result = new[]{0}
             .Concat(arr.Select((x,i)=>new {x,i})
             .Where(a=>a.x<0).Select(a=>a.i+1))
             .Select (i => arr.Skip(i).TakeWhile(a => a>=0))
             .OrderByDescending(a=>a.Sum())
             .OrderByDescending(a=>a.Count()).First();
```

However usually you want to do these as a single loop..

```
var result=new List<int>();
var maxResult=new List<int>();

// These next four variables could be calculated on the fly 
// but this way prevents reiterating the list each loop.
var count=0; 
var sum=0;
var maxCount=0;
var maxSum=0;

foreach (var value in arr) {
  if (value >=0) {
    result.Add(value);
    sum+=value;
    count++;
  } else {
    if (sum>maxSum || (sum==maxSum && count>maxCount)) {
      maxSum=sum;
      maxCount=count;
      maxResult=result;
    }
    result.Clear();
    count=0;
    sum=0;
  }
}

var returnValue=maxResult.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static int[] FindMaxArrayEx(int[] srcArray)
    {
        int[] maxArray = new int[1];
        int maxTotal = int.MinValue;
        int curIndex = 0;
        int tmpTotal = 0;
        List<int> tmpArray = new List<int>();

        if (srcArray.Length != 1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < srcArray.Length; i++)
            {
                tmpTotal = 0;
                curIndex = i;
                tmpArray.Clear();

                while (curIndex < srcArray.Length)
                {
                    tmpTotal += srcArray[curIndex];
                    tmpArray.Add(srcArray[curIndex]);

                    if (tmpTotal > maxTotal)
                    {
                        maxTotal = tmpTotal;
                        maxArray = tmpArray.ToArray();
                    }

                    curIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            maxTotal = srcArray[0];
            maxArray = srcArray;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("FindMaxArrayEx: {0}",maxTotal);

        return maxArray;

    }
```

Comment: Care to give some explanation?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a totally working solution:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class MaxSumOfSubArray
{
    static void Main()
    {
        //int[] array = { 2, 3, -6, -1, 2, -1, 6, 4, -8, 8 };
        //maxSubSum(array);

        int digits;
        List<int> array = new List<int>();
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter array of integer values. To exit, enter eny key different than 0..9");

        while (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out digits))
        {
            array.Add(digits);
        }

        maxSubSum(array);
    }

    public static void maxSubSum(List<int> arr)
    {
        int maxSum = 0;
        int currentSum = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int seqStart=0;
        int seqEnd=0;
        while (j < arr.Count)
        {
            currentSum = currentSum + arr[j];

            if (currentSum > maxSum)
            {
                maxSum = currentSum;
                seqStart = i;
                seqEnd = j;
            }
            else if (currentSum < 0)
            {
                i = j + 1;
                currentSum = 0;
            }
            j++;
        }
        Console.Write("The sequence of maximal sum in given array is: {");
        for (int seq = seqStart; seq <= seqEnd; seq++)
        {
            Console.Write(arr[seq] + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\b}");
        Console.WriteLine("The maximum sum of subarray is: {0}", maxSum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// given an non-empty input array of integers, this method returns the largest contiguous sum
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="inputArray">the non-empty input array of integeres</param>
    /// <returns>int, the largest contiguous sum</returns>
    /// <remarks>time complexity O(n)</remarks>

    static int GetLargestContiguousSum(int[] inputArray)
    {
        //find length of the string, if empty throw an exception            
        if (inputArray.Length == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("the input parameter cannot be an empty array");

        int maxSum = 0;
        int currentSum = 0;

        maxSum = currentSum = inputArray[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < inputArray.Length; i++) //skip i=0 as currentSum=inputArray[0].
        {
            currentSum = Math.Max(currentSum + inputArray[i], inputArray[i]);
            maxSum = Math.Max(currentSum, maxSum);
        }
        return maxSum;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

/*--This was the algorithum I found on Wiki to calculate sum, however to get the actual subarray
             * I really had to think. After spending few hours I was able to solve it using startIndex and 
             * endIndex int variables and then by adding a if clause if (max_ending_here == array[i])
                                { startIndex = i; }
             * dang this was very tough. I hope you all will refactor as needed to make some improvements.*/

```
/*  Initialize:
            max_so_far = 0
            max_ending_here = 0

        Loop for each element of the array
            (a) max_ending_here = max_ending_here + a[i]
            (b) if(max_ending_here < 0)
                    max_ending_here = 0
            (c) if(max_so_far < max_ending_here)
                    max_so_far = max_ending_here
        return max_so_far*/

        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Text;
        namespace ConsoleApplication3
        {
            class Program
            {
                static void Main(string[] args)
                {
                    int[] array = { -2, 1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5, 4 };
                    int[] largestSubArray;
                    largestSubArray = Max_Array(array);
                    Console.WriteLine();

                    Console.WriteLine("Subarray is :");
                    foreach (int numb in largestSubArray)
                        Console.WriteLine(numb);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }

                //Max_Array function will calculate the largest contigent array
                //sum and then find out startIndex and endIndex of sub array
                //within for loop.Using this startIndex and endIndex new subarray
                //is created with the name of largestSubArray and values are copied                           
                //from original array. 

                public static int[] Max_Array(int[] array)
                {
                    int[] largestSubArray;
                    int max_so_far = 0, max_ending_here = 0, startIndex = 0,
                        endIndex = 0;

                    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
                    {
                        max_ending_here += array[i];

                        if (max_ending_here <= 0)
                        {
                            max_ending_here = 0;
                        }

                        if (max_ending_here == array[i])
                            { startIndex = i; }

                        if (max_so_far < max_ending_here)
                        {                                
                            max_so_far = max_ending_here;
                            endIndex = i;
                        }
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Largest sum is: {0}", max_so_far);

                    largestSubArray = new int[(endIndex - startIndex) + 1];
                    Array.Copy(array, startIndex, largestSubArray, 0, (endIndex - startIndex) + 1);
                    return largestSubArray;

                }
            }
        }
```

> ## Output
>
> ```
> Largest sum is: 6
> ```

```
'Subarray is:
4,
-1,
2,
1'
```

Comment: This algorithm fails with inputs like: -1,-2,-3 or 1, -2, 3, 4, -10, 6

Answer (score 0):

It's not that complicated once you go over it. I thought about it going backwards at first, that helped for some reason.

1. If all numbers are positive (or 0), the entire array would be the largest subarray with max sum.
2. Now, we can take this fact and apply it over positive or negative arrays and instead say that we want to include all subarrays that are positive (or 0).
3. Start at the end and sum as you go left. When you find a negative number, you think, did that negative number make the rest of my sums worthless? if not, you keep going.. but you also mark that point right there as the current max sum (if it's greater than the last current max sum).
4. If they are worthless, (ie sum is now less than 0), you know that everything to the right of your index is now worthless. You still keep your current max sum in case thats the highest though.
5. start from 3 with your new index. Keep track of the indexes for your current max sum and end.

Answer (score 0):

The SubArray with Maximum Sum in an Array is the Array without the Minimum most element element. So sort it. and remove the minimum element. thats it.
Thats applicable if Its Only Positive Integer Array. Otherwise the subarray of Positive elements only is the answer

Answer (score 0):

below code working for me :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string str = Console.ReadLine();
            int [] arr = Array.ConvertAll(str.Split(' '),int.Parse);
            int curSum = 0, maxSum = 0;
            curSum = maxSum = arr[0];
            for (int i = 1; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                curSum = Math.Max(curSum + arr[i], arr[i]);
                maxSum = Math.Max(curSum, maxSum);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", maxSum);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Input : -2 1 -3 4 -1 2 1 -5 4

O/P: 6